# View does not seem to be saving all the information in my model

Tags: django, django-models, python-3.6

I have a model and a view for saving books. However, when I access the information it does not appear to be complete. All queries seem to be running properly. I'm at a loss what could be going wrong

my model

```
class Book(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
      cover_pic = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
      author = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
      description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
      uploaded_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

      def __str__(self):
        return self.title

      def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("books:addBook")

      class Meta:
        ordering = ["-uploaded_on"]
```

My `views.py`

```
class addBook(FormUserNeededMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = BookForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('addbook')
    template_name = 'books/addbook.html'
```

`forms.py`

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        exclude = ['user', 'uploaded_on']
```

am trying to access the details using this view

```
class BookListView(ListView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'books/viewbooks.html'
```

and this template

```
{% for books in object_list %}
  <img src="{{ book.cover_pic }}">
  <h5>{{ book.title }}</h5>
  <p>{{ book.author }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

everytime I add an item I can see another list item added in view books but has none of the details that I requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop variable is `books` not `book`. Rename one of them, for example the one in the for tag:

```
{% for book in object_list %}
  <img src="{{ book.cover_pic }}">
  <h5>{{ book.title }}</h5>
  <p>{{ book.author }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Now the title and the author are appearing but not the picture. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help! Now you need to figure out how to show a picture from a FileField, good luck.

Comment: Image is not working for me despite confirming file has been uploaded to correct folder. am getting 404