# Images not being served in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, image, django-models

My media which i have uploaded using the form in this question [View does not seem to be saving all the information in my model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55419739/7534176) is being uploaded to the correct /media/images folder that i have defined. However, on access it returns a 404. 
i have tried to follow the instructions on https://stackoverflow.com/a/39359264 but still am getting a 404.

my template code

```
{% for books in object_list %}
    <img src="{{ books.cover_pic.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
] 
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my model code for the image is

```
cover_pic = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/')
```

my media folder is at base dir (next to manage.py).
What am i overlooking?

Comment: Did you try adding `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` to your `urls.py`

Comment: yes. I forgot to add my urls.py. Added now

Comment: Are you running it with `DEBUG=False`?

Comment: No DEBUG=True. @BurhanKhalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It works for me  this way.  You also try some method that I commented in the models.py incase 
of anything.

**settings.py**

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = (
BASE_DIR
)


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**models.py ...**

```
#Here you can try changing FileField to ImageField if you like.
# You can also try directory uploads as image without backslash
#cover_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')

cover_pic = models.FileField(upload_to='images/')
```

**urls.py(project's)**

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**template (.html)**

```
  {% for books in object_list %}
    <img src="{{ books.cover_pic.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The error was in putting the static settings url in the app urls.py and not the project wide urls.py. Thank you. It works now.